# Count the number of ordered triples of positive integers whose product is not greater than a given number?

Tags: riemann-hypothesis, divisor-counting-function, ramanujan-summation

Given N, count the number of ordered triplets(a,b,c) whose product $abc \leq N$.
I have found the series [here](http://oeis.org/A061201) .
But I am not sure I understand Benoit Cloitre work which proposed an efficent way to compute.
$O(N)$ computation is simply not good enough, I need something sublinear . Possibly between $O(N^{8/9})$ and $O(N^{2/3})$.

EDIT:
As discussed with @henry here is my [code](https://ideone.com/ggY53e) from my broken interpretation of Andrew Lelechenko's formula

Comment: What do you think about the Andrew Lelechenko comments on your linked sequence?

Comment: @Henry $a(n) = 3*Sum_{i=1..n3} A006218(n/i) - Sum_{j=1..n3} floor(n/(i*j)) + n3^3, where n3 = floor(n^{1/3}) $ what do you think order of this is ? Please help me understand if you have.

Comment: Lets focus on A006218. If that can be done in $n^{1/3}$ then I am done as overally complexity will be $n^{2/3}$. It says $a(n) = n * ( log(n) + 2*gamma - 1 ) + O(sqrt(n))$ What does O(sqrt(n)) mean ?

Comment: From my interpretation of the formula I am writing this code. which is definitely not the series. while the referenced series is generated correctly. https://ideone.com/ggY53e What am I misreading ?

Comment: $O(sqrt(n))$ mean that the error grows no faster in magnitude than a multiple of $\sqrt{n}$.  It is not a complexity  calculation for the exact result

Comment: I got my formula corrected. The `3` multiple should be there on both inner and outer loop. But I am still not happywith my complexity. We can probably do better than $n^{5/6}$ that we have.

Comment: the referred series has $O(n^{1/2})$ complexity using the deterministic method and if we use the appoximation formula the result is too erroneous to work with.Can we find something combining both to get the value with certainty and also reduce the time down from $O(n^{1/2})$ to  $O(n^{1/3})$

Comment: Put more effort into your question. $N ≠ n$.